# security concerns with mapping home and site url to SERVER_NAME

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I am researching different methods to allow Wordpress to work without additional configuration when I work from dev, testing, and prod environments. One possible solution is to simply set the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME constants to the SERVER_NAME value in the wp-config.php file as [mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754209/make-wordpress-available-from-any-domain):

```
$domain = sprintf('%s://%s', 
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? 'http' : 'https', 
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_SITEURL',       $domain);
define('WP_HOME',          $domain);
```

Could this cause any security loopholes?

Thank you!

Comment: server_name comes from the server config, e.g. httpd.conf. however, note that not all sites run on port 80. you're forcing https on any site which is NOT on the default port. You should reverse the logic and force `http` on any site not running on port 443.

Comment: That's a good point. I just copied this solution from the link above, but I'll definitely change that logic if I decide going this route is feasible.

Comment: Not all `https` sites run on port 443 either. (Although admittedly this is far less common than `http` not running on port 80.)

Comment: Why not use `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']`?

Comment: I set a variable in the vhost and check for it in the wp-config. if it is set then it is the development server, and set different DB - URL constants. if it's not set it's live and I set the live constants. this way wp-config never has to be changed between servers